# How would I fix this code to allow me to leave one channel when switching to the next

Tags: javascript, twilio

This is what I have to switch between channels in the chat, but it does not leave the channel even when calling the .leave() function

```js
  new Twilio.Chat.Client.create(data.token).then(function(chatClient) {
      $(".change-channel").on("click", function(){
        if ($(this).text() == "General Button"){
          if(currentChannel != "general"){
            chatClient.getSubscribedChannels().then(joinChannel(chatClient, 'general','General Chat Channel'));
            currentChannel.leave();
          }
          // if not current channel general then:

        }
        if ($(this).text() == "Specific Button"){
          if(currentChannel != "generals"){
            chatClient.getSubscribedChannels().then(joinChannel(chatClient, 'generals','Generals Chat Channel'));
            currentChannel.leave();
          }
          // if not currentchannel generals then:
        }
     });
    });
```

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't leave the channel? What is happening?

Comment: When I switch from one channel, like "general", to "generals" It never actually leaves the "general" channel and I can still see messages being sent from the "general" channel even though it says i am in the "generals" channel @philnash

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Comment: What do you mean you still see messages being sent from the general channel? Are you calling `channel.sendMessage` on the wrong channel? Or are messages arriving to your event handler for that channel still?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I think the channels may be getting confused as you join and leave them and promises and callbacks are resolved. I would try making sure that you have left the channel first, before joining the next one and disallowing the switching of channels while the process is going on.

Something like this:

```
new Twilio.Chat.Client.create(data.token).then(function(chatClient) {
  let currentChannel, nextChannel, nextChannelName;
  let changingChannel = false;

  // fired when a channel has been left completely
  chatClient.on('channelLeft', channel => {
    chatClient.getSubscribedChannels()
      .then(joinChannel(chatClient, nextChannel, nextChannelName));
  })

  // fired when a channel has been successfully joined
  chatClient.on('channelJoined', channel => {
    currentChannel = channel;
    changingChannel = false;
    nextChannel = nextChannelName = null;
  })

  $(".change-channel").on("click", function(){
    if (changingChannel) {
      // already switching channels, don't do anything
      return;
    }

    if ($(this).text() == "General Button"){
      if(currentChannel.uniqueName != "general"){
        changingChannel = true;
        nextChannel = 'general';
        nextChannelName = 'General Chat Channel';
        // start the process to leave the channel
        currentChannel.leave();
        currentChannel = null;
      }
      // if not current channel general then:

    }
    if ($(this).text() == "Specific Button"){
      if(currentChannel.uniqueName != "generals"){
        changingChannel = true;
        nextChannel = 'generals';
        nextChannelName = 'Generals Chat Channel';
        // start the process to leave the channel
        currentChannel.leave();
        currentChannel = null;
      }
      // if not currentchannel generals then:
    }
 });
});
```

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: Hi, it is coming back with the error that it cannot read property 'uniqueName' of undefined @philnash

Comment: That is probably because there is a situation in which there is no `currentChannel` set. I just built upon the code you started with, so I don't know how you set it in the first place. That is up to you.